# c# edit txt file without creating another file (without StreamWriter)

Tags: c#, file, stream

Because I'm using non-latin alphabet, if I use StreamWriter, the characters aren't correct.

```
        String line;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\John\Desktop\result.html");
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (line.Contains("</head>"))
            {
                line = "<img src=\"result_files\\image003.png\"/>" + line;
            }
        }
        sr.Close();
```

Here I'm editing the string I want to edit in the file, but I'm not saving it in the same file. How to do that?

Comment: pls take a look at this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/InsertTextInCSharp.aspx

Comment: I think that in your code snippet you just manipulate string in the heap, StreamReader is just for read not for write, which non-latin alphabet are you trying to write? is it ></ signs?

Comment: You can set the encoding on the StreamWriter

Comment: But I don't always have this file. Maybe the encoding will be different.

Comment: It's not clear from your last comment exactly where the problem is. Are you getting incorrect characters when reading the file or when you write it back to a new file? Do you actually want a new file or do you just want to modify the existing file?

Comment: The title says "without creating another file", right?
I'm getting incorrect characters in the output file.

Comment: Sorry, missed that :o I have updated my answer to write back to the original file. If you can provide a link to a file that isn't working I can test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use one of the [StreamWriter constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzyh741c%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) that accepts an encoding you shouldn't have any problems with incorrect characters. You are also skipping the first line in your reading method.

```
Encoding encoding;
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    string line;
    encoding = sr.CurrentEncoding;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("</head>"))
        {
            line = "<img src=\"result_files\\image003.png\"/>" + line;
        }
        output.AppendLine(line);
    }
}
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, false, encoding))
{
    writer.Write(output.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This gives me an empty output.

Comment: I just retested and it works fine for me. I just used it to copy a text file.

Comment: No problem. I just edited the example to always use the encoding from the original file.

Comment: Actually, I have strange characters again.

Comment: Can you post a link to a file that I can test with?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest approach would be

1. open the file in read/write mode
2. read everything from the file
3. make the modifications inmemory
4. rewrite it back to the file rather than appending..

Answer (score -4):

you use a StreamReader. And the name say what it's function. To read!

Dirty-Code

```
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            int counter = 1;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string s in File.ReadAllLines(fileName, Encoding.Default))
            {
                if (s.Contains("</head>"))
                {
                    s= "<img src=\"result_files\\image003.png\"/>" + line;
                }

                    sb.AppendLine(s);

                counter++;
            }

            File.WriteAllText(fileName, sb.ToString(), Encoding.Default);
        }
```